# How can I load PHP classes without having to write long class names during object creation?

Tags: php, directory, autoload

I'm trying to figure out how to exactly autoload classes in PHP. It seems like I keep running into having to write really long class names when creating new objects. This is kind of annoying depending on the folder structure.

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath('.'));

function __autoload($class_name)
{
    $path = APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "lib" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class_name . ".php";
    if (file_exists($path))
        require_once $path;       
}


$customer = new AppName\Models\Customer();
echo $customer->GetName();

$cr = new AppName\Repository\CustomerRepository();
echo $cr->GetName();
```

I know I can use a use statement to shorten it, but then I'd have to write a bunch of use statements.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or maybe something I am missing to make it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You have either write the full name of the class or write the use statements.